# Possibly deprecated JDBC MySQL driver in iReports, can't import new one

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ireport

I need to use JasperReports (which I've never used before) to make an application generate some reports from a database, and was told iReports Designer is the best (if not only) for formatting and stuff. I'm running iReports 5.6.0 for Windows, the latest version I could find.

My application connects to the database using the MySQL Connector/J API 8.0, specifically driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver, and I'm not allowed to change that. But the closest iReports has is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, which I believe is Connector/J 5.1. It obviously doesn't connect to the database, throws the following error:

```
SQL problems: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{database_name}
```

I've tried to import the 8.0 connector into iReports through the classpath and the service window, and it either doesn't show up or just imports as com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, even though it's the same .jar from the Maven folder I'm using in the Java application. I suspect it has something to do with iReports being old and just plain not supporting it, but I'm required to work with JasperReports in this project, so I'm really open to any ideas or workarounds you may have.

Comment: Given the new MySQL Connector/J 8 contains a `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class for backwards compatibility, likely you have either only the old version or more than one MySQL Connector/J version on the class path for iReport and the old version gets loaded first. Please describe all the steps you used to _"[..] import the 8.0 connector into iReports through the classpath and the service window"_.